# jQuery to parse HTML from JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I have created an ajax call using jQuery that returns  HTML content in a JSON format. However, when the content is shown in the screen HTML tags (like break tag, paragraphs tags) are beeing processed as HTML. How can I make so that i won't see those tags in the screen. Below is my code

```
$.ajax({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: url,  
          data: dataString,
          dataType:'JSON',  
          success: function(data) {  
            var mywindow = window.open('','_blank', 'mydiv');
            mywindow.document.write(data);
            mywindow.print();
            //reload receitas
            $.ajax({
                 url: "<?php echo $this->baseUrl();?>/paciente/Ajax/loadreceitas",
                 dataType : 'html',

                 beforeSend:function(){
                    $("#receitasList").html("<img src=\"<?php echo $this->baseUrl();?>/imgs/ajax-loader.gif\">");
                 },
                 success: function(data) {

                    $("#receitasList").html(data);
```

Comment: Can you post the JSON data in the success callback? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a jQuery object and extract the text from it.

```
$('#receitasList').html($(data).text());
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment below, you would need to replace existences of `<br />`.

```
$('#receitasList').html(data.replace('<br />', ''));
```

Comment: if i do that i will get only the text in the table. the html content for the table will be striped out

Comment: i should had been more clear my apologies. the response of my json has html in it, to be more precise a table tag that contains all the content to be displayed. this content might have break tags paragraphs tags, etc.right now it is displaying the tags instead of being processed as html.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text(data)`, not `.html(data)`.

Comment: didn't work. thid is what i see :1 Comprimido Pra Dor De Cabeca<br /> <br /> 3 Aspirinas A Noite<br /> <br /> De Manha. I don't want the user to see <br /> but proccess it as html instead
thank you

Comment: So... do you want it as HTML, or do you want it as text? Make up your mind!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be the escape function from zend. I took it out then it worked like a charm. thank you everybody for the fast replies. happy coding to everyone.